# Determine percentage of screen covered by an object without using frustum culling

Tags: 3d, screen, bounding-boxes, frustum-culling

On the CPU-side of an 3D first-person / ego perspective game I need to check whether what the players currently sees on screen is the inside of a box object defined by world space coordinates (the player might be outside of that box but on screen sees only/mostly the inside of the box, or vice-versa, looks from within the box to the outside).

The "casual" way of performing such a check would incorporate frustum culling but such an approach would be hard to achieve with my given set of engine parameters which I'd like to avoid if there is a simpler way.

What I actually have at the point where I would like to do the check (high-level script on CPU, not GPU side):

- Camera world position
- Camera direction
- Camera FOV
- Two Box corner world coordinates (left-bottom-front, right-top-back)

What I do not have right away:

- View frustrum definition (near/far plane or say 6 planes defining
  frustum)
- Any specific pixel information (uv, view space position, depth or the
  like)

What I would like to calculate:

- **Percentage of screen "covered" by box.**

Any hints on how to perform such calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a rough sketch of an algorithm that might do this.

Use the camera to calculate an inverse view projection matrix. Then transform **all** the cube's vertices using this matrix. You now have all the vertices in screen space (-1~1). Compute the convex hull of all these vertices and then clip this convex hull inside the screen space. You now have a polygon of which you can compute the area. The total area of the screens space is 4 so its easy to compute a percentage and this method is independent on resolutions and aspect ratios.

Comment: I hope you are not implying that screen space (window-space) is [0,1] with this statement: *"You now have all the vertices in screen space (0~1)"*. About the only thing in window-space that is usually in that range is the depth, as the default depth range in most APIs is [0,1]. I also cannot figure out where the idea of window-space having an area of **1** comes from? Are you thinking of some different coordinate space? Even NDC is actually [-1,1] in X and Y, thus it would have an area of **4**. Can you elaborate?

Comment: My bad it is indeed [-1,1] with an area of 4. Just a simple mistake.

Comment: Thanks; "Use the camera to calculate an inverse view projection matrix" how would I do this? Not sure I understand...

Comment: Normally you use your camera and its look at to calculate a normal view-project matrix. For the inverse see http://www.gamedev.net/topic/595333-inverse-of-view-projection-matrix/

Comment: Thank you. Would there be a yet simpler way, without all those matrix calculation stuff? I had thought of some check using the view angles between the camera direction and the view vector (direction) to the cube's corners or center point. That way I could for example determine whether a certain point (i.e. corner vertex) is located inside or outside of the screen boundaries, only be checking view angle and distance, thus avoiding the requirement of any world-to-screen-space or whatever matrix calculations.

Answer (score 0):

According to the book Real-Time Cinematography for Games, the fastest but least accurate way to do this is by calculating the projection of an object's bounding sphere onto the viewplane of the camera.

r = f*r_w / (**v** . (**p_w** - **q**))

Where:

f = focal length

r_w = bounding sphere radius of the object

**v** = normalized camera direction

**p_w** = bounding center of object

**q** = camera location

. = dot product

Finally, the area of the object on the screen space is:

a = PI*r^2

Similarly you can project the 8 corners of the bounding box onto the screen plane and calculate the bounding box area.